# How to match "0 0 0" exactly using python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to match all "ALL ZEROs" from the following command output.

```
router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#
```

I need to meet the following requirements:

I tried with following code:

```
x="""router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#"""

def pass_fail_criteria(x):
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+"):
        print "FAIL"
    else:
        print "PASS"

print pass_fail_criteria(x)
```

But its throws following error:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python test_regexp.py
  File "test_regexp.py", line 17
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+"):
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Is it possible to match only all zero's with exact spaces?

Comment: There are two questions, here ... The answer to the first one is ... close the ** bracket !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a regex like

```
\s*\w+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

This would seem to match

```
gmail    0   0   0
```

An alternative (at your request) is to match the literal `0`'s. Just replace the digit match with 0:

```
\s*\w+\s+(0)\s+(0)\s+(0)
```

Note that the (parentheses) are for grouping, and may not be necessary depending on how you'll be using the regex. If you're just testing for a match, you can drop them.

Then you should probably write a function to ensure the matches are all 0.

You might take a look at [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ifUey22l6z1pnOCf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to match all exact zeros, without using function. My basic idea is to use this with Robot Framework "Should Not Match Regexp" keyword. URL "http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.6.1#Should%20Match%20Regexp".

Comment: \s+\w+\s+(0)\s+(0)\s+(0)... Can I use this? Is it valid?

Comment: Absolutely. Follow the debuggex link, copy paste some code, and work on the matches.

Comment: A space is required before "gmail" in your example.

Comment: @rcubefather - that regex will only work if the application name can't have spaces in it. Since you are trying to match "0" exactly, you don't need to use parans to setup capture groups. Try `".{23}0                 0                  0"`.

Comment: That's strange... the stackoverflow code quoters is getting rid of needed spaces. Try `".{23}0 +0 +0"`